# Qt setStyleSheet which kind of fonts can I use?

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, qpushbutton

Do anyone know, which kind of fonts are available in Qt to format the font of a widget. Are they system specific? I want to have numbers in modern digits like [this](http://www.dafont.com/de/ds-digital.font)
Can I implement this font in my program? And if I can, how to do it?

Comment: Last I checked, this information is on Google. You should find all your answers there.

Comment: While using `QLCDNumber` is an OK solution, bundling the `DS Digital` font will probably look nicer and be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Qt doesn't include any fonts in its distribution. I did a quick search to verify and couldn't find any. You can use any TrueType font installed on your system, so yes, the available fonts are system specific.

An alternate approach is to build a font file into your executable as a Qt resource, and then install that font for your application to use by using the `QFontDatabase` class. Once you have your resource file built--see the "Qt Resource System" in the docs--here's the code for installing a font.

```
#include <QFontDatabase>

int result = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont (":/fonts/SomeFont.ttf");

if (result == -1)
{
    // Some kind of appropriate error handling
}
```

You need to call this code once at the beginning of your program, and then the font is available by name just as if it were installed onto the system wherever your program is running. Note that this does NOT install the font on the local system; the font will be available only to your application.

Also note that fonts are licensed items, so in order to be legal when you distribute your application, you either need to be licensed to distribute the font(s), or you need to find open source fonts that provide appropriate licenses allowing for free redistribution.

Comment: I found an alternative solution on my own. It is to use QLCDNumber. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oh! I'd forgotten about that...never used it, but it's a pretty cool little widget and exactly what you need. Glad you found it.